# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de mapear el ID de una entidad usando Nhibernate y teniendo una base de datos Oracle sql?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, nhibernate

una consulta. La aplicación es un **`MVC de asp.net`**, usando **`Nhibernate`**.
En los mapeos me encuentro que algunas entidades tienen

```
Id(x => x.Id, "ID").GeneratedBy.Native();
```

mientras que otras tienen

```
Id(x => x.Id, "ID").GeneratedBy.Native("Nombre_de_la_secuencia");
```

La base de datos es un Oracle.

Lo que quiero saber es si se trata de un error en el mapeo no indicar el nombre de la secuencia, o si al no indicarlo se busca automáticamente una secuencia con el nombre "`Seq_Nombre_Entidad`" por ej.

**`ACLARACIÖN: la base de datos usa oracle versión Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production y la versión de Nhibernate es v4.0.30319`**

Comment: si generas un insert de la entidad que no define el nombre de la secuencia, genera el registro ? si lo hace que valor de id esta asignando? Entiendo que el Native() va a responder diferente dependiendo de la implementacion del provider de base de datos. Para Oracle entiendo deberias indicarlo, pero lo mejor es realizar una prueba de insert a ver que genera como id del registro por defecto. Puede que la implementacion para Oracle tome un default sino se indica ninguna secuencia. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820750/error-caused-by-generatedby-statement-in-mappings-when-running-tests